# Replace surrounding quote in vim-surround with string

Tags: vim

I'm using vim-surround, I'm trying to replace:

```
'this text needs to be replaced'
```

with

```
**this text needs to be replaced**
```

I've done both yss and cst (ie.):

```
:cst**
:yss**
```

and both only captures up to the first *.

How do I surround text with a string?

HTML tags obviously works fine, I guess they detects the first instance of '<' and opens up input buffer but for other text that doesn't seem like its possible.

Comment: Did you try surround's issue tracker?

Answer (score 4):

You can customize behavior in VIM e.g.

```
let g:surround_42 = "**\r**"
```

or file based where `txt` is a file type

```
autocmd FileType txt let b:surround_42 = "**\r**"
```

Where 42 is a ASCII value for `*`. Then change the surrounded text object as usual with single `*` and it will be replaced with `**`.

Comment: Another way to write it:  `let g:surround_{char2nr('*')} = "**\r**"`. I find this improves maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

From the `sorround` help file:

```
A replacement argument is a single character, and is required by |cs|, |ys|,
and |vS|.  Undefined replacement characters (with the exception of alphabetic
characters) default to placing themselves at the beginning and end of the
destination, which can be useful for characters like / and |.
```

So actually you can use only a single character in the substitution. Anyway `surround` can be customized, and you can adopt the solution proposed in the other answer.

But in this case why not use some plain `vim` substitution?

```
:s/'/**/g
```

You can then repeat this change on another line with `@:`

Answer (score 0):

If you have both [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) and [repeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat), you could do this:

```
ysi'*
.
ds'
```

So what it does:

1. surround the text inside the quotes with asterisks.
2. repeat the previous command.
3. delete the surround quotes.

Note, this doesn't work if you don't have `repeat.vim`, which handles `.` for plugin maps and such.